# Decrypt tor traffic

Tags: encryption, packet-sniffers, tor, packet-injection

I got a tor client using on mashine in my local network, so I capture all traffic.
Also I can redirect all tor traffic on any server/client, add some clients in network, modify or inject every packet from this mashine.

So, is there way to decrypt this tor traffic or just see requested resources?

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to see requested resources is DNS-sniffing. If client isn't encapsulate DNS-requests traffic into tor network and requested only internet (not tor internal) resources you can capture network packets between client and DNS-server.

Comment: This man works only througth tor network. Sure, i got all not encapsulated DNS-requests.